# Is it necessary to continue charging the phone batteries for first time for 4 hours?

Tags: batteries

I am a beginner in electronics
I had a question, is it important to charge the battery for the first time to continue charging the battery for several hours after it is fully charged?
Because some sellers say this, but I don't know if this is scientifically correct or not

tnx for any help

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed.  While it's borderline, the OP is asking if there is an engineering reason why a manufacturer would want the battery to remain on the charger after it's fully charged.  I think that's a legitimate question for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary.  Once the battery is fully charged there's no need to keep it connected to the charger.

The only reason I can think of for the recommendation is that some battery gauges need a full charge/discharge cycle to improve the gauge accuracy, so the recommendation may be to ensure the battery is actually fully charged (as the gauge may be reporting full or close to full when it's not yet actually full) but worst-case the next time you charge it overnight it should recalibrate.

Comment: Also, tech service gets tired of people thinking that their device has malfunctioned, when it is just a dead battery.